# Can we use VAST for HLS streaming? Is it possible to send m3u8 files in VAST tags

Tags: javascript, html, ads, vast

We are implementing video player with the VAST pre-roll, mid-roll, and post-roll video advertisement support.

Is it possible to send m3u8 files in VAST tags? I gone through the specification of vast and vast tags examples there is no where I able to find about this info.

Answer (score 1):

Techically vast does not prevent you from using any media formay you want. Your problem could be the video players trying to render that format.